# User.Claims Is Empty In MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm working on upgrading my .NET Core 2.2 MVC application to 3.0. In this application I'm authenticating to a controller using a JWT token. The token contains several claims, but when I try to access them through `User.Claims` the resulting list is always empty.

In my `Startup.cs` I have the authentication setup like so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Code removed for clarity //

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = JwtManager.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = "MyAudience",
                    IssuerSigningKey = "MySigningKey"
                };
            });
    }
}
```

In Core 2.2 I was able to access my claims using code similar to the following:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("MyController/Action")]
    public ActionResult<Aggregate[]> GetAction()
    {
        var username = User.FindFirstValue("MyUsernameClaim");
        if (username == null)
        {
            return Forbid();
        }       
        // Do Stuff //
    }
}
```

However, when I migrate the same code to Core 3.0, I authenticate properly, but I get no claims for the `User` object. 
[image]

Did I miss a step in converting this to 3.0? Does `User` not get automatically populated with information anymore or something?

Comment: Can you confirm that the user is authenticated? I can't see from the image but `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` seems false. If so, then this may have to do with the AuthenticationScheme.

Comment: How did you configure routing? Did you add UseRouting, UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization in that order before UseEndpoints? Can you show that piece of code?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I moved `UseEndpoints` to the end of the `Configure` method and that fixed things. Holy cow, I can't believe something so simple like that has cost me an embarrassing amount of time. If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the user isn't authenticated at all.

With asp.net core 3.0 routing has changed to Endpoint routing. You can opt-out by setting `EnableEndpointRouting = false`.

But that seems not the case here. That means you'll have to include certain services when you use them, like authentication and authorization:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  ...

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
```

And most important, *in that order*. As documentated here: [Migrate Startup.Configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure).

Comment: For more information about the order, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order)

Comment: I was missing  the app.UseAuthentication();